# How to migrate from belongs_to, to embedded_in in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

If one first build their models with a belong_to and has_many association and then realized they need to move to a embedded_in and embeds_many association, how would one do this without invalidating thousands of records? Need to migrate them somehow.

Answer (score 4):

I am not so sure my solution is right or not. This is something you might try to accomplish it.

Suppose You have models - like this

```
#User Model
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :books
end

#Book Model
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title
  belongs_to :user
end
```

At first step I will create another model that is similar to the Book model above but it's embedded instead of referenced.

```
#EmbedBook Model
class EmbedBook
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title
  embedded_in :user
end

#User Model (Update with EmbedBook Model)
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :embed_books
  has_many :books
end
```

Then create a Mongoid Migration with something like this for the above example

```
class ReferenceToEmbed < Mongoid::Migration
  def up
    User.all.each do |user|
      user.books.each do |book|
        embed_book = user.embed_books.new
        embed_book.title = book.title
        embed_book.save 
        book.destroy
      end
    end
  end
  def down
    # I am not so sure How to reverse this migration so I am skipping it here
  end
end
```

After running the migration. From here you can see that reference books are embedded, but the name for the embedded model is EmbedBook and model Book is still there

So the next step would be to make model book as embed instead.

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user
  field :title
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :books
  embeds_many :embed_books
end
```

So the next would be to migrate embedbook type to book type

```
class EmbedBookToBook < Mongoid::Migration
  def up
    User.all.each do |user|
      user.embed_books.each do |embed_book|
      book = user.books.new
      book.title = embed_book.title
      book.save 
      embed_book.destroy
    end
  end
  def down
    # I am skipping this portion. Since I am not so sure how to migrate back.
  end
end
```

Now If you see Book is changed from referenced to embedded.
You can remove EmbedBook model to make the changing complete.

- This is just the suggestion. Try this on your development before trying on production. Since, I think there might be something wrong in my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I took your suggestion and created some rake tasks for migration.

Answer (score 1):

10gen has a couple of articles on data modeling which could be useful:

- [Data Modeling Considerations for MongoDB Applications](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/)
- [Embedded One-to-Many Relationships](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)
- [Referenced One-to-Many Relationships](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)
- [MongoDB Data Modeling and Rails](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/model-data-for-ruby-on-rails/)

Remember that there are two limitations in MongoDB when it comes to embedding:

- the document size-limit is 16MB - this implies a max number of embedded documents, even if you just embed their object-id
- if you ever want to search across all embedded documents from the top-level, then don't embed, but use referenced documents instead!

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

1. In `User` model leave the `has_many :books` relation, and add the
       embedded relation with a different name to not override the `books`
       method.

   ```
       class User
          include Mongoid::Document

          has_many :books
          embeds_many :embedded_books, :class_name => "Book"
       end
   ```

   Now if you call the `embedded_books` method from a `User` instance
      mongoid should return an empty array.
2. Without adding any embedded relation to `Book` model, write your own
   migration script:

   ```
   class Book 
      include Mongoid::Document

      field :title, type: String
      field :price, type: Integer
      belongs_to :user

      def self.migrate
         attributes_to_migrate = ["title","price"] # Use strings not symbols, 
                                                   # we keep only what we need. 
                                                   # We skip :user_id field because 
                                                   # is a field related to belongs_to association.
         Book.all.each do |book|
            attrs = book.attributes.slice(*attributes_to_migrate)
            user = book.user // through belong_to association
            user.embedded_book.create!(attrs)
         end
      end 
   end
   ```

   Calling `Book.migrate` you should have all the Books copied inside each user who was
   associated with belongs_to relation.
3. Now you can remove the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relations, and
   finally switch to clean embedded solution.

   ```
   class User
      include Mongoid::Document

      embeds_many :books
   end

   class Book 
      include Mongoid::Document

      field :title, type: String
      field :price, type: Integer
      embedded_in :user
   end
   ```

I have not tested this solution, but theoretically should work, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have a much shorter concise answer:

Let's assume that you have the same models:

```
#User Model
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :books
end

#Book Model
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So change it to embeds:

```
#User Model
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :books
end

#Book Model
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title
  embedded_in :user
end
```

And generate a mongoid migration like this:

```
class EmbedBooks < Mongoid::Migration
  @@attributes_to_migrate = [:title]
  def self.up
    Book.unscoped.where(:user_id.ne => nil).all.each do |book|
      user = User.find book[:user_id]
      if user
        attrs = book.attributes.slice(*@@attributes_to_migrate)
        user.books.create! attrs
      end
    end
  end

  def self.down
    User.unscoped.all.each do |user|
      user.books.each do |book|
        attrs = @@attributes_to_migrate.reduce({}) do |sym,attr|
          sym[attr] = book[attr]
          sym
        end
        attrs[:user] = user

        Book.find_or_create_by(**attrs)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works because when you query from class level, it is looking for the top level collection (which still exists even if you change your relations), and the `book[:user_id]` is a trick to access the document attribute instead of autogenerated methods which also exists as you have not done anything to delete them.

So there you have it, a simple migration from relational to embedded